# how do i prevent the scanner from accepting strings, negative integers, or numbers less than 2?

Tags: java, try-catch, java.util.scanner

How do i prevent negative numbers from being returned by this method? 
I have tried setting the while loop to

```
(n < 0 && n != 0)
```

to no avail.
Here is my code for the method currently:

```
public int getNumber() {          
       int n = 1;
       while(n < 2 && n != 0) {
           if(n < 0) {
               System.out.print("Error, please enter a valid number greater than 0(0 to exit): ");               
               scan.next();
               n = scan.nextInt();
           }
       try {           
           System.out.print("Enter the upper bound(0 to exit): ");
           n = scan.nextInt();           
           break;
       }
       catch(java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
           System.out.print("Error, please enter a valid number greater than 0(0 to exit): ");
           scan.next();
           continue;
           }      
       }
       return n;      
   }
```

I have also tried to put my if statement inside the try block like this:

```
public int getNumber() {          
       int n = 1;
       while(n < 2 && n != 0) {

       try {           
           System.out.print("Enter the upper bound(0 to exit): ");
           n = scan.nextInt();
           if(n < 0) {
               System.out.print("Error, please enter a valid number greater than 0(0 to exit): ");               
               scan.next();
               n = scan.nextInt();
           }
           break;
       }
       catch(java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
           System.out.print("Error, please enter a valid number greater than 0(0 to exit): ");
           scan.next();
           continue;
           }      
       }
       return n;      
   }
```

When i put the if statement inside the try block, i started to input negative numbers consecutively to test. It worked for the first time i entered a negative number, then gave me a blank scanner input line, and then finally allowed a negative number to return, which in turn screws the rest of my program up. Please help, im a first semester student in java. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You input a negative number, then it goes into your n<0 if and you put in another one and then break out of the loop.
Try changing your if to:

```
while(n < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `while` loop condition for validating input. Your loop condition does not give your program a chance to accept and check the number before making a decision to keep or to reject the entered value. As the result, your program starts prompting end-users with an error message even before they typed anything.

You should not call `nextInt` without first checking if the `Scanner` is ready to give you an `int` by calling `hasNextInt`.

Finally, you need a rejection loop to throw away non-integer input until `hasNextInt` succeeds. This is usually done with a nested `while` loop, which prints an error prompt, and throws away the entered value.

The overall skeleton for reading and validating an `int` looks like this:

```
System.err.println("Enter a number between 0 and 5, inclusive");
int res = -1;
while (true) {
    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
        System.err.println("Incorrect input. Please enter a number between 0 and 5, inclusive");
        scan.nextLine(); // Discard junk entries
    }
    res = scan.nextInt();
    if (res >= 0 && res <= 5) {
        break;
    }
    System.err.println("Invalid number. Please enter a number between 0 and 5, inclusive");
}
// When you reach this point, res is between 0 and 5, inclusive
```

Answer (score 0):

couldn't you just check for 'hasNextInt', then test the input.

```
int n = 0;
System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 and 5);
while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
    n = scan.nextInt();
    if (n >= 0 && n <= 5) {
        break;
    }else{
        //prompt error message or handle however you wish
    }
}
return n;
```

likewise you could also force with an unsigned integer.

Answer (score 0):

Final code to not return negative integers or strings:

```
public int getNumber() {
       System.out.print("Enter the upper bound(0 to exit): ");
       int nums = 1;
       while(true) {
           while(!scan.hasNextInt()) {
               System.out.print("Error. Please enter a valid integer greater than 1(0 to exit): ");
               scan.nextLine();
           }
           nums = scan.nextInt();
           if(nums > 2 || nums == 0) {
               break;
           } else {
               System.out.print("Error. Please enter a valid integer greater than 1(0 to exit): ");
               scan.nextLine();
           }
       }
      return nums;
   }
```

Thanks a million you guys!